# Travis Java build using different SDK for compilation and tests

Tags: java, travis-ci

I have a library that uses Java 8 classes if they are available and for older JRE versions provides a fallback implementation. It means I have to compile using Java 8 (or higher) but I want to execute the tests with JDK 7 to test the fallback. I can not figure out how to do it in Travis.

Comment: I guess you already use a build matrix? If so, yould you post your matrix configuration? Thx

Comment: It seems that the answer is here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html now I just need to find the path to Java 8 JDK

Comment: Yeah but AFAIK, you still need the `jdkswitcher`. In any case, you could store the path to the jdk (or the desired jdk version) in environment variables specific to each build matrix element. That's why I asked for your build matrix configuration (if you have any).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create special Maven profile for Travis in pom.xml

```
   <profile>
      <id>travis</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <executable>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac</executable>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

And then activate it in .travis.yml

```
script: mvn install -P travis
```